# Is there a FCM Service in Google API PHP Client Services

Tags: php, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-api-php-client

I have looked through Github but could not find any related class or documentation.

https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services/tree/master/src/Google/Service

I am trying to send an FCM message from the server to a web client. Below is how I am currently achieving that.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/json');

$data = array(
    'message' => array(
        'notification' => array(
            'title' => 'FCM Message',
            'body' => 'This is an FCM Message',
        )
    )
);

$server_key = 'ya29.ElqKBGN2Ri_Uz...HnS_uNreA';

$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$headers = 'Authorization:key = '.$firebase_api_key."\r\n".'Content-Type: application/json'."\r\n".'Accept: application/json'."\r\n";

$registration_ids = array('bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...');
$fields = array('registration_ids' => $registration_ids, 'data' => $data);

$content = json_encode($fields);
$context = array('http' => array( 'method' => 'POST', 'header' => $headers, 'content' => $content));
$context = stream_context_create($context);
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

print($response);
```

But I am hoping there is a Google Service I can use for the sake of future compatibility. See the example below.

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/json');

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/service-account.json');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

$data = array(
    'message' => array(
        'notification' => array(
            'title' => 'FCM Message',
            'body' => 'This is an FCM Message',
        ),
        'token': 'bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...'
    )
);


$fcm = new Google_Service_FirebaseCloudMessaging($client);
$response = $fcm->send($data);

print($response);
```

Comment: Note: Replace : (colon) with => (equals greater than) in you example to be correct syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FCM Service has been added on 2019-05-17 update

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client-services/commit/29cd38940096a3e973ad348d69101d1c2f1526d8#diff-dfabf19b00a6fe639dc70ab311952848

Answer (score 7):

**First generate a private key file for your service account:**

1. In the Firebase console, open **Settings > Service Accounts** (https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk).
2. Click **Generate New Private Key**, and confirm by clicking **Generate Key**.
3. Securely store the JSON file containing the key.

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1

**Install the Google Client PHP sources via composer**

```
$ composer require google/apiclient
```

**Now use the API**

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=' . __DIR__ . '/api-project-1234567-firebase-adminsdk-abcdefg.json');

$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging');

$http_client = $client->authorize();

$message = [
    'message' => [
        'token' => 'dG****:****r9jM',
        'notification' => [
            'body' => 'This is an FCM notification message!',
            'title' => 'FCM Message',
        ],
    ],
];

$project = 'api-project-1234567';

// Send the Push Notification - use $response to inspect success or errors
$response = $http_client->post("https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{$project}/messages:send", ['json' => $message]);

echo (string)$response->getBody() . PHP_EOL;
```

Of course you have to replace the **token** with the receiver token, the **credentials file** with that one you have downloaded in the first step and the **project** with your project id.

I found the solution here: https://gist.github.com/Repox/64ac4b3582f8ac42a6a1b41667db7440

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!  For Google APIs, I needed to use this syntax instead of the `'json' => $message` syntax above: `$response = $http_client->post($endpoint, [GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => $message]);
 `